# Autodesk Forge uploadObject API fails to upload a file 30MB to 100MB files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-data-management

I am uploading files locally using the ForgeSample project, but I can't upload files that are larger than 20MB. The largest files I've tried were a 84MB and a 52MB file, which is less than the recommended size before you should use resumable upload endpoint. I don't received any errors it just doesn't upload. As soon as I try uploading another small file (20MB or less) and refresh, everything loads up just fine. Link to sample project I used (https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/oss/).

I wrote my own code and ran in to this same issue, which is what prompted me to try the above sample to see if there was a difference in what I was doing.

So my question is should I have to use the resumable endpoint if my files are a lot smaller than 100MB, if not how can I go about doing that successfully?

If I have to use resumable upload is there an example that allows you to stream files from one storage service like AWS S3 to OSS. The example I've seen assumes you're uploading from client. I ask because this is my ultimate goal, as I can successfully transfer small files from S3 to OSS, but can't for previously mentioned sizes. I'd appreciate any help or a point in the right direction. Thanks.

[Snapshot of Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olpli.png)

Comment: Maybe sever is limit the size upload. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try [buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/)

You may then split larger files into chunks and specify a range in the header for each request to upload the chunks to avoid timeouts and other networking issues, e.g.:

```
curl -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/bucketexamplekey/objects/objectKeyFoo/resumable"
  -X PUT
  -H "Authorization:Bearer p0vNqwggSc4EOJdhR4KkTVyJFIzQ"
  -H "Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
  -H "Content-Range:bytes 1-15/100"
  -H "Session-Id:-811577637"
  --data ...
```

You can also try these tools below to upload large objects in chunk:

- [Forge Tools Hub](https://forge-tools-hub.now.sh/uploader) (guide [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/meet-forge-tools-hub-jamstackserverless-tools-download-derivatives-svf-and-view-models-offline))
- [Forge Node CLI](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-cli-utils)
- [Forge VSCode Plugin](https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools)